# How can I specifiy that a Cargo package may only be compiled on some platforms?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm writing a binary Rust crate that is specifically built around a command-line program that only exists on Linux. Is there a way I can specify that it may only compile on Linux, as a Windows or OS X version just wouldn't make any sense? What is the best approach here?

Comment: *"specifically built around a command-line program that only exists on Linux"* Out of curiosity, what program is this? Rarely is shelling-out to an external program the best solution, for reasons such as this question.

Comment: I don't think there's a Cargo setting to specify possible target architectures. You can check the target in your build script, though, and error out if it's not one of the supported architectures.

Comment: You can warn in the README that the program only works on Linux when said cli program is already installed, since anyway it'll only work on Linux if said cli program is installed.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart the program is [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/). I can see that it's not a good practice in most cases, but I think it's fine here as the binary isn't supposed to be directly run by the user; it's a docker credential helper, so (linux) users will install it to their path and then when docker needs to authenticate it runs my program to get the details from pass. It's a weird sort of modularity that docker allows but that's the system I'm working within!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matiu's answer may be useful in some cases, but I don't want to adopt cargo-make just for this. I also considered writing a build script but there doesn't seem to be a way to force it to run the build script every time you try to compile.

In the end I think the best way is just to document clearly that it only works on linux.

Comment: pass is available on macOS btw: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/pass

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [cargo-make](https://github.com/sagiegurari/cargo-make#commands-scripts-and-sub-tasks) with `condition = { platforms = ["linux"] ...`